# Using amsthm but still getting "Environment theorem undefined"

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm

I'm trying to write up all my university theorems and I cant get the theorem environment to work. Here is a mini example of what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\vect{\underline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bi}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}

\title{Theorems\\ Y3 S1}
\author{Hannahl}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Mathematical Methods}
\begin{theorem}{Placheral's Theorem}
||F||^2_2 =2\pi ||u||^2_2 
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I get this error

! LaTeX Error: Environment theorem undefined.

I am using windows 7 have MikTex 2.9 installed and am using TexMaker.
From what I have read the theorem environment should be part of the amsthm package which I have. But it isn't working!

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please fix spelling of "Plancherel" in your real document.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a more proper way to do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{mathtools} % Bonus
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Methods}
\begin{theorem}[Placheral's Theorem]
  \begin{equation*}
\norm{ F }^2_2 =2\pi \norm{ u }^2_2 .
\end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

---

As one might have guessed `\newtheorem` constructs theorem environments. Use it to define your Theorem, Lemma, etc. environments. You might want to have a look at `\theoremstyle` as well. Here is a handy method for defining an example env which is not italic.

```
\theoremstyle{definition} % amsthm only
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

As `tohecz` mentions, you may want to read up on this subject. Details for `amsthm`, can be found in `amsthdoc.pdf`.

The `\newtheorem` syntax should be covered by any standard LaTeX introduction.

Comment: You might want to more clearly point out that a missing `\newtheorem` is the real problem ;)

Comment: Ahh that's very useful, I think I had misunderstood a few things there.

Comment: @Hannah: And the environment has an optional argument instead of a mandatory.

Comment: @Hannah Well, I'm tempted to say RTM -- read the manual ;)

Comment: no actual environments are predefined by any class or package supporting theorem-class objects -- it's not known what an author might want to call them, especially if said author is working in a language other than english.  so `\newtheorem` is *always* required.  if you're working with a tex live installation, try typing `texdoc amsthm` at a prompt to view the (`amsthm`) manual.

Comment: @barbarabeeton,the op is using miktex, it's texdoc is not as good as the one on TeX live, so it might very well be that `texdoc amsthm` does not give a result on miktex because the actual manual is called something else (yet another reason I recommend tl to our users)